# How does distplot/kdeplot calculate the kde curve?

Tags: python, seaborn, kernel-density

I'm using seaborn for plotting data. Everything is fine until my mentor asked me how the plot is made in the following code for example.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.normal(size=100)
sns.distplot(x)
plt.show()
```

The result of this code is:

[image: plot result]

My questions:

1. How does `distplot` manage to plot this?
2. Why does the plot start at `-3` and end at `4`?
3. Is there any parametric function or any specific mathematical function that `distplot` uses to plot the data like this?

I use `distplot` and `kind='kde'` to plot my data, but I would like to know what is the maths behind those functions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation

Comment: The start and end of the plot is determined by the random data. As there are only 100 values, it is highly likely that they aren't perfectly symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code trying to illustrate how the kde curve is drawn.

The code starts with a random sample of 100 xs.

These xs are shown in a [histogram](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html). With `density=True` the histogram is normalized so that it's full area would be 1. (Standard, the bars of the histogram grow with the number of points. Internally, the complete area is calculated and each bar's height is divided by that area.)

To draw the [kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html), a [gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) "bell" curve is drawn around each of the N samples. These curves are summed, and normalized by dividing by N.
The `sigma` of these curves is a free parameter. Default it is calculated by Scott's rule (`N ** (-1/5)` or `0.4` for 100 points, the green curve in the example plot).

The code below shows the result for different choices of `sigma`. Smaller `sigma`s enclose the given data stronger, larger `sigma`s appear more smooth. There is no perfect choice for `sigma`, it depends strongly on the data and what is known (or guessed) about the underlying distribution.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def gauss(x, mu, sigma):
    return np.exp(-((x - mu) / sigma) ** 2 / 2) / (sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))

N = 100
xs = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)

plt.hist(xs, density=True, label='Histogram', alpha=.4, ec='w')
x = np.linspace(xs.min() - 1, xs.max() + 1, 100)
for sigma in np.arange(.2, 1.2, .2):
    plt.plot(x, sum(gauss(x, xi, sigma) for xi in xs) / N, label=f'$\\sigma = {sigma:.1f}$')
plt.xlim(x[0], x[-1])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: Instead of a histogram or a kde, other ways to visualize 100 random numbers are a set of short lines:

```py
plt.plot(np.repeat(xs, 3), np.tile((0, -0.05, np.nan), N), lw=1, c='k', alpha=0.5)
plt.ylim(ymin=-0.05)
```

or dots (jittered, so they don't overlap):

```py
plt.scatter(xs, -np.random.rand(N)/10, s=1, color='crimson')
plt.ylim(ymin=-0.099)
```